# replacing many words every one with alternative word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to replace many words with alternative Tags(or words). Every word has a specific tag but it will take so much time to do it with find and replace.

Can any formula help with this situation?

I have three columns:

1. the first column have sentence with the word I want to replace
2. the second column have all words I want to replace
3. next to it in the third column the replacement word or new tag.

```
+---+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|   |            A            |             B              |             C             |
+---+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1 | sentence word1 sentence |                 word3      |                      tag3 |
| 2 | sentence word2 sentence |                 word6      |                      tag6 |
| 3 | sentence word3 sentence |                 word8      |                      tag8 |
| 4 | sentence word4 sentence |                 word9      |                      tag9 |
| 5 | sentence word5 sentence |                 word10     |                     tag10 |
+---+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: You can use [SUBSTITUTE()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

Comment: In your example, I don't see `word3` in your sentence `word1`. Is this just an error in the example, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A UDF does the trick

After investigating `=substitute()` in the array form I settled on a UDF.  Paste the following code into a new module in the workbook you need this done in.

In excel you can use the function as any other function. `=FindReplace(` : hit ctrl-shift-a and it will ask you for the criteria.

Example:  `=FindReplace(A1,$B$1:$B$2,$C$1:$C$2)`

```
    Function FindReplace(Cell As Range, Old_Text As Range, New_Text As Range) As String

    Dim i As Long, text As String, Old_T() As Variant, New_T() As Variant

    FindReplace = Cell.Value
    Old_T = Old_Text.Value
    New_T = New_Text.Value

    For i = LBound(Old_T) To UBound(Old_T)
        FindReplace = Replace(FindReplace, Old_T(i, 1), New_T(i, 1), 1)
    Next i

    End Function
```

Comment: if you would like to select entire columns for old text and new text i suggest adding `If Old_T(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For` before the line `FindReplace = Replace(FindReplace, Old_T(i, 1), New_T(i, 1), 1)` NOTE: if you are going to have blanks in between values in the old text column do not do this. – Joshua Fenner 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

You can use following UDF

```
Function SubstituteMultiple(str As String, old_txt_rng As Range, new_txt_rng As Range)
    Dim i As Single
    For i = 1 To old_txt_rng.Cells.Count
        Result = Replace(LCase(str), LCase(old_txt_rng.Cells(i)), LCase(new_txt_rng.Cells(i)))
        str = Result
    Next i
    SubstituteMultiple = Result
End Function
```

As per the image below enter `=SubstituteMultiple(A2,$B$2:$B$6,$C$2:$C$6)` in `Cell D2` then drag/copy down as reuired.

[image]

Got this from [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/02/27/substitute-multiple-text-strings-vba/).