# replace 2 or 3 words in one sentence in one cell from another words in another cell on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was looking for a solution and I found it here

[replacing many words every one with alternative word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529366/replacing-many-words-every-one-with-alternative-word)

But now I'm using a alternative code that I've got from the link below that post, which is case sensitve.

```
Function SubstituteMultipleCS(text As String, old_text As Range, new_text As Range)
Dim i As Single
For i = 1 To old_text.Cells.Count
    Result = Replace(text, old_text.Cells(i), new_text.Cells(i))
    text = Result
Next i
SubstituteMultipleCS = Result
End Function
```

I'm using it to make German Anki cards so I need  to replace some words with ___. It's working with one single word or a bunch of words if they are together, but...

**The problem is the following:**
Some verbs conjugation have a sentence structure when I must place the main verb after the noun and the particle, which belongs to the verb, at the end. Something like this

[image: example]

As you can see in the picture, the verb "schaute an" is not replaced by the new word because "schaute" is separated from "an" in the original sentence.

Is there any way to fix this?

thank you.

Comment: You could another loop through the word to replace by splitting into words using space as delimiter,

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: Der Glatzkopf __ den Zöllner finster __

Comment: Can you search for each word separately? Anki cards are usually only one sentence,

Comment: I didn't copy properly the whole code, now it's there.

Comment: No, sadly I can't do it separately

Comment: Yes, the thing is that the anki cards that I use are more complex than back/front. The first field must be the whole word that I'm studying.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to open another loop. My knowledge is limited :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula you may use (which works for your current sample data:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"."," ")&" "," "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() = 1]")&" ",D2,1),IFERROR(" "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() = 2]")&" ",""),D2,1),IFERROR(" "&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() = 3]")&" ",""),D2,1))&".","")
```

The advantage of nested substitutes is that we can tell the function to only replace the first occurence if you had a sentence where multiple could occur. Not sure if it's watertight.

Comment: It's done. Sorry it was my first post, I've seen the clapping hands and the top arrow but not the check haha

Comment: All good @Reycobos. I hope the answers helps you out. Good luck.

Comment: I've been using the formula for some days but I found out something that I don't know how to change. There is a problem with commas , the formula doesn't work with them. My example has a dot at the end, it's not really common (around 15%) but it's more common when a words ends in a comma. I've been playing with the formula some hours and I can replace commas instead dots, but the formula will delete all the commas and just keep one. And of course, I couldn't get how it works with both commas and dots at the same time...